# Proper way to iterate throught list of pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I can't wrap my head about idea of array of pointers. Problem is I'm trying to iterate throught list of pointers (or at least get second value from pointer's array). I understand that `integer` is 4 bytes long (assuming im on 32-bit). And what I'm trying to do is get first address that points to a[0] and add to this address 4 bytes, which in my opinion will result in a[1]. However, this works as I'm just adding value to index. I.e. `f[0] + 4 -> f[5]`
And I don't quite understand why.

```
 #include "stdio.h"
    int main()
    {
        int a[6] = {10,2,3,4,20, 42};
        int *f[6];
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); i++) f[i] = &a[i];
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); i++) printf("Current pointer points to %i\n", *(*f+i));
        printf("The is %i", *(f[0]+sizeof(int)));
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: warning: pointers are not always 4 bytes!

Comment: Your example does not work the way you probably think it does, due to operator precedence in `*(*f+i)`.

Comment: Never rely on a given size of variables - except for the three `char` types, but even those can have 8 or more bits.

Comment: `int *f[6], *p; for (i = 0, p = f[0]; i < 6; i++, p++) printf("%p %d\n", p, *p);`

Comment: C already knows the sizeof things, so it knows that a[1] is 4 bytes past a[0] (assuming 32 bit ints).  If you want to play around with the addressing yourself you need to use 'char' pointers (via assignment or casting).

Comment: @EOF This was just an example of printing values. Problem is when I'm trying to iterate throught memory values

Comment: @Olaf so with char pointers I can safely increment memory values and access them ?

Comment: @Disciples: Not clear how you come to this conclusion. Please read a good C book to learn the language properly. And feel free to read the standard, too. That's nothing to explain in a short comment and videos are definitively not a good resource for learning such basics.

Comment: `*(*f+i)` should be `*f[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic takes into account the size of the pointer.
`f[0] + 4` will multiply 4 by the size of the integer type.
Here's an online disassembler: https://godbolt.org/.
When I type the code `f[0] + 4`, the disassembly appears as

```
add     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 16
```

Meaning it has multiplied the 4 by 4 (32-bit = 4 bytes) to make 16.

Comment: So looks like I can't iterate throught list of pointers in that way? By adding to pointer sizeof variable's type it points to?

Comment: If you have a pointer, and want to iterate through its values, you either use `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { doSomethingWithValue(pointer[i]); }` or `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++, pointer++) { doSomethingWithValue(pointer); }`. C takes care of the size of the values.

Comment: Thanks for your code example.
And in that case I can't directly access memory which will be incremented by sizeof ?

Comment: If you want to access memory values in between, you'll probably end up breaking some aliasing rule, and end up with unaligned memory operations which will crash some architectures. This shouldn't be a problem though, as if you need finer grain control you'll be using a different value type in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

An array is a pointer to a chunk of RAM. `int a[6] = {10,2,3,4,20, 42};` actually creates a chunk with `[0x0000000A, 0x00000002, 0x00000003, 0x00000004, 0x00000014, 0x0000002A]`, and `a` points to where the list starts.

Using an index `a[n]` basically means `go to the position of a (start of the array), then advance by n*sizeof(int) bytes`.

- `a[0]` means `Go to position of a, then don't jump`
- `a[1]` means `Go to position of a, then jump 1 time the size of an integer`
- `a[2]` means `Go to position of a, then jump 2 times the size of an integer`

supposing `a` is at the address `0xF00D0000`, and you're on a 32bit machine:

```
a[0] // Pointer to 0xF00D0000
a[1] // Pointer to 0xF00D0004
a[2] // Pointer to 0xF00D0008
a[32] // Pointer to 0xF00D0080
```

I hope this makes sense.